# Sending one http request with data from multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, xmlhttprequest

I have a React native app

In this app, the user fills up a form and click submit

The form is built from multiple components (text, image, dropdown menu) and each component holds his own data

When the user clicks submit, I would like to send one request with all of data to the server

What is the preferred way of doing so in React? Maybe creating a getter function for each component and call it using refs?

Is splitting the request to multiple requests will be better?

Comment: What did you try so far? the common pattern is to have a stateful parent component that holds the current values for the different inputs in a state. When the inputs change they report the change by calling an onChange handler provided by the parent. When the user clicks submit you validate the state object and send it. There are a great number of tutorials that explain that in detail. Your inputs should be controlled meaning that the do not hold the value themself but receive it as a prop together with an onChange handler.

Comment: Have a look at this example from the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components